# how to number custom blocks in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a R Markdown document with numbered sections.

I want to create some custom blocks with their own numbering (for example for some exercices)
Exercice 1, exercice 2, exercice 3, etc.

Should I use custom css counters to do this according to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp ? How to do this? is the solution can be used github flavoured markdown for github publishing ?

Comment: @RaphaelS Yes it is.

Comment: I hope that answered it then!